# Always send jupyterlab stdout to ipywidgets Output widget

Tags: jupyter-lab, ipywidgets

I am using the following code in a particular jupyterlab cell

```
from ipywidgets import Output
out = Output(layout={'border': '2px solid black', 'height': '150px', 'overflow_y': 'scroll'})
display(out)
with out:
    print("hello")
```

That nicely creates a "textbox" under my cell and the output of 'print' goes to it.

**I want all of my cells to behave this way**

Once I've instantiated `out`, I can create a context in every cell, but I'd like it such that every output that normally goes just under a cell will instead go into an Output ipywidget below its individual cell.

Is this possible?